# Oracle query for the attached output

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where I need to show daily transactions and also total transaction for that month with date and other fields like type, product etc.
Once I have that, the main requirement is to get the daily percentage of total for that month, below is an example of it. 3 transaction on 1st jan and 257 for total of jan and the percentage of 1st jan is (3/257)*100, similarly 10 is for 2nd jan and the percentage is (10/257) and so on.
can anyone help me with the sql query?

```
Date    Type    Transaction Total_For_month Percentage
1/1/2017    A   3   257 1%
1/2/2017    B   10  257 4%
1/3/2017    A   5   257 2%
1/4/2017    C   8   257 3%
1/5/2017    D   12  257 5%
1/6/2017    D   17  257 7%
```

Comment: So, the report is for data for one month at a time? Or do you need a report for a full year (say), where the total and the percentage for month is reported separately for each day?

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(transaction) over (partition by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')) as total_for_month,
       transaction / sum(transaction) over (partition by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')) as ratio
from t;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions130.htm#SQLRF00691

Answer (score 0):

DATE and TYPE are Oracle keywords, I hope you are not using them literally as column names. I will use DT and TP below.

You didn't say one way or the other, but it seems like you must filter your data so that the final report is for a single month (rather than for a full year, say). If so, you could do something like this. Notice the analytic function `RATIO_TO_REPORT`. Note that I multiply the ratio by 100, and I use some non-standard formatting to get the result in the "percentage" format; don't worry too much if you don't understand that part from the first reading.

```
select   dt, tp, transaction, sum(transaction) over () as total_trans_for_month,
         to_char(100 * ratio_to_report(transaction) over (), '90.0L', 
                                               'nls_currency=%') as pct_of_monthly_trans
from     your_table
where    dt >= date '2017-01-01' and dt < add_months(date '2017-01-01', 1)
order by dt   --  if needed (add more criteria as appropriate).
```

Notice the analytic clause: `over ()`. We are not partitioning by anything, and we are not ordering by anything either; but since we want every row of input to generate a row in the output, we still need the *analytic* version of sum, and the analytic function `ratio_to_report`. The proper way to achieve this is to include the `over` clause, but leave it empty: `over ()`.

Note also that in the `where` clause I did not wrap `dt` within `trunc` or `to_char` or any other function. If you are lucky, there is an index on that column, and writing the `where` conditions as I did allows that index to be used, if the Optimizer finds it should be.

The date '2017-01-01' is arbitrary (chosen to match your example); in production it should probably be a bind variable.